# Unwind dictionary values in mongodb aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, metabase

I need to create some plots from single documents existing in mongodb. I can only use the mongodb aggregation framework (so for example I cannot just pull the documents into python and work with it there). I am using the query builder of metabase, so I am limited from this regard.

In order to do this, I am first using some `$match` queries in order to identify the documents that I need to look at (these are predefined and static). After the `$match` stage, I am left with one document (this is ok) with the following structure.

```
{
 "id": 1,
 "locs": {
    "a":1,
    "b":2, 
    "c":3
  }
}
```

I need to change this structure to something like this:

`[{"a":1}, {"b":2}, {"c":3"}]`

or any other form that would allow me to create pie charts out of the structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert `locs` object to array using [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). Now [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `locs` array to split into multiple documents. Use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with [**`$push`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator to make the split data again into `k` and `v` format. And finally use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with the final `data` field to move it to `$$ROOT` position.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": { "data": { "$objectToArray": "$locs" }}},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$data",
    "data": { "$push": { "k": "$data.k", "v": "$data.v" }}
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

Comment: You rock! It worked almost perfectly, I just needed to add a { "$unwind": "$data" } before the $replaceRoot step.

Comment: Can this be done in the aggregation pipeline without `$objectToArray` / `$arrayToObject` (prior to 3.4.4)?

Comment: @Frayt No. It would be better if you update your mongo version because new versions are introduced for comfortableness